# Avoid cache sw.js with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, service-worker, server-side-rendering

I have a `SSR` React *Application* served by `nginx` reverse proxy, with a proxy caching configured for the *App* `location`. Something like:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:8m max_size=50m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

location / {
  proxy_cache mycache;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
  add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  # all the other configuration for this location
}
```

I am using [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) *Webpack* plugin to handle all the *Service Worker* lifecycle and set an [event](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin/blob/master/docs/updates.md) when the SW has updates.

Before set the `nginx` cache configuration, the SW behaviour was:

- after the first time loaded the *App* (and all the sw process done), browser has `sw.js` and works well without internet connection
- deploy new code
- new browser window after checking no other window with same url is open
- `sw` detect updates, the relative process to cache new assets, then the event mentioned earlier (that in my case fires a window refresh to ensure all the content is new)

After set the `nginx` cache configuration (example code shown earlier) the process described  didn't happen. The only way make it happen is to make a *hard-refresh* cleaning the `cache` of the *browser*. In that case get a fresh `sw.js` that detect changes and so on.

Of course browsing in *private* mode fires always the events from the start (install sw, cache, etc).

I noted that the file `sw.js` is cached (see below) and also that returns the *Header* `x-proxy-cache: HIT`, confirming that the file served is from cache.

[image: sw-cached]

Since it's necessary to obtain always a fresh `sw.js` I tried doing something like:

```
location /sw.js {
  expires -1;
  add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
}
```

But when doing this rule in the `nginx` sites-enabled configuration the `sw.js` file have a bad response. Browsing a new session I get:

[image: sw-bad-response]

Also found there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1687#issuecomment-308404079) in [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) but as far as I know this boilerplate don't do SSR (remarking the SSR point to show the differences, maybe helps to understand better the point  but don't know if is related to the issue).

Comment: Set up logging for nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/), what error is logged when it tries to serve the SW script?

Comment: fwiw this feels like it has nothing to do with service worker, and is purely an nginx config issue. If you simply navigate to the script url, what happens?

Comment: navigating to /sw.js doesn't found it ☹️ (when adding the conf block), returns a great "404 Not Found (nginx)"

Comment: Does it work if you add the `proxy_cache` line into the new location block?

Comment: so, to have `proxy_cache` either in `/` and `/sw.js` blocks, right?

Comment: In both blocks.

Comment: Seems solved adding `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/sw.js;`, since I have  `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` directive in the `/` location block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158623/discussion-between-lionel-t-and-jaffa-the-cake).

Comment: Ok, Jake, adding `proxy_pass` in the new block works as expected: the `sw` make the updates, then reload the page (since I added window.location.reload() to `onUpdated` method of offline-plugin) but, since the page was cached, the next time I navigate to the url, calls wrong .js files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define specific cache control header for selected file only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963293/define-specific-cache-control-header-for-selected-file-only)