# Define specific cache control header for selected file only

Tags: nginx, gatsby, cache-control

I'm setting up a Nginx sever (version 1.17.1) for Gatsby following up the recommendation at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/caching/.

The snippet below is the portion my [`server {}`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) block attempting implementing the recommended caching configuration;

```
location ~* \.(?:html)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
}

location /static {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
}

location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
}

location /sw\.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
}
```

Equally tried an [if statement](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) in place of the [`location {}`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) block for defining cache configuration for the service worker file, `sw.js`, as below;

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^sw\.(?:js)$) {
    set $no_cache 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, all files get cached successfully as expected except `sw.js`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it so as to effectively set cache control header for `sw.js` to `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`?

Comment: It is unclear, do you want `sw.js` cached or not? If yes, why don't you just remove the part of configuration specific to that file and treat is as any other?

Comment: @DusanBajic: I want to cache all JavaScript files except `sw.js`. Any idea about what I can do to achieve that? Will equally appreciate an edit to making my post clearer. Many thanks. 

Comment: So with the above config, `sw.js` is getting cached (like all other js files), but only that one you don't want cached?

Comment: Yes @DusanBajic: with the configuration above, `sw.js` get cached just as all JavaScript files. That's what I want to prevent, so as to cache all JavaScript files except `sw.js`.

Comment: Move `location` snippet that handles `sw.js` to the top of the rules, and use exact match: `location = /sw.js { ...`

Comment: @DusanBajic: Many thanks ; it's now working just fine after following your recommendation. Do you mind posting an answer to explain what the issue were with my previous configuration settings and why it needed to be altered to exact match and on top of all rules please?

Comment: Didn't you forget the `/page-data` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of precedence of `location` is described here https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

When an exact match is found (using the `=` modifier) the search terminates and regular expressions will not be checked, so you can use that for your `sw.js`:

```
location = /sw.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that it needs to be declared at the top?

Comment: @RobinWieruch: Yes.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up with the following nginx configuration regarding caching for Gatsby.js:

```
        location ~* \.(?:html)$ {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location /page-data {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location = /sw.js {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location /static {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
        }

        location ~* \.(?:js|css)$ {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
        }
```

@OP: With which configuration did you end up? Maybe you can edit this answer to match the perfect solution after all; for people searching for "caching nginx gatsby".